# Assign "Share" functionality to a custom button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, branding

I want to assign the OOTB "Share" functionality of SharePoint 2013 to a custom button. How to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

The OOB share button just pops open a dialog to the appropriate page.  So just hit that share button and figure out which page it's opening (aclinv.aspx with some query string options), and hook up a dialog.

```
<input type="button" onclick="OpenShareDialog()" value="share" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function OpenShareDialog() {
    var options =
     {
         url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/aclinv.aspx?forSharing=1&mbypass=1&IsDlg=1",
         dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null, dialogClosedCallback)    
     };
     SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);    
}

function dialogClosedCallback(result, target) {
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Derek, its not working. DO I need to change anything in querystring?

Comment: How are you deploying the code? Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

put this in Your onclick function for this button

```
    EnsureScriptFunc('sharing.js', 'DisplaySharingDialog', function(){DisplaySharingDialog('\u002f')});
```

this will be the same as hitting OOB share button which is in the upper right corner of the page.

best to paste this line in console of browser dev tools (F12) and check if works.